# Is it true that $\|M(I-M)^{-1}\|_{\infty} \leq \frac{\|M\|_{\infty}}{1-\|M\|_{\infty}}\,?$

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

I've encountered a non-symmetric matrix $M$ with nonnegative elements ($M_{ij} \geq 0$), satisfying $\|M\|_{\infty} < 1$, which I need to bound. Is it true that

$$
\|M(I-M)^{-1}\|_{\infty} \leq \frac{\|M\|_{\infty}}{1-\|M\|_{\infty}}\,?
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. This is a consequence of the geometric series and $\left\|AB \right\|_{\infty} \le \left\|A \right\|_{\infty}\left\|B \right\|_{\infty}$. To wit, since $\left\|M\right\|_{\infty} < 1$, then 
\begin{align}
(I-M)^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} M^{k}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\left\|M(I-M)^{-1}\right\|_{\infty} 
&\le 
\left\|M\right\|_{\infty}\left\|(I-M)^{-1}\right\|_{\infty}\\
&\le
\left\|M\right\|_{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left\|M\right\|_{\infty}^{k}\\
&=
\frac{\left\|M\right\|_{\infty}}{1-\left\|M\right\|_{\infty}}
\end{align}